# Need to enter a value in a specific cell of the same row that value was found and continue to last row

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet that has 4 Columns of dates based on when a project has to be completed. Of those 4 dates it needs to determine if it is Today and if so enter value "Send Reminder" in a specific column of the same row that it found it in. Example N5:Q5 have dates in them, if any of those dates are Today then "Send Reminder" needs to populate in R5. Then go to next row N6:Q6 and repeat this till it finds an empty row. I can get it to check all my rows and columns but I can't figure out the second part, it keeps putting it in R5 even if the date is in N15(it should populate R15) and that is where I got lost.

Here is what I have so far.

````
Sub RowReminder()

Dim cll As Range
Dim Rng As Range
Set Rng = Range("N5:Q5", Range("N5:Q5").End(xlDown))


    For Each cll In Rng
        If cll.Value = Date Then
            Range("R5").Value = "Send Reminder"
            Range("R5").Interior.Color = vbYellow
        End If
    Next cll
End Sub```
````

Comment: Change `Range("R5")` to  `Range("R" & cll.Row)` or `Cells(cll.Row, "R")`

Comment: This fixed my problem. Thank you so much! I was almost out of hair.

Comment: Please have a look on my answer. There are some hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `Range("N5:Q5").End(xlDown)` is not reliable to locate the last data row in column N to Q. Actually, it is equivalent to `Range("N5").End(xlDown)`.
- Identify the last row for each column and determine the maximum row number.
- Insert `Exit For` after updating the data in column R, ensuring the inner loop exits upon finding a matching cell to save time.
- You have the flexibility to use either `Range` or `Cells` to reference a cell in column R.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub RowReminder()
    Dim rCell As Range, rRow As Range
    Dim rRng As Range, LastRow As Long, iRow As Long
    For Each rCell In Range("N5:Q5")
        iRow = Cells(Rows.Count, rCell.Column).End(xlUp)
        If iRow > LastRow Then LastRow = iRow
    Next
    If LastRow > 4 Then
        Set rRng = Range("N5").Resize(LastRow - 4, 4)
        For Each rRow In rRng.Rows
            For Each rCell In rRow.Cells
                If rCell.Value = Date Then
                    Range("R" & rCell.Row).Value = "Send Reminder"
                    Cells(rCell.Row, "R").Interior.Color = vbYellow
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next rCell
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Range.End property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.comP/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.end?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144121)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [Range.Resize property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.comP/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.resize?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)